# Paella and seafood casserole

Tags: seafood, paella

What is the difference between "seafood casserole" and "paella"?

Answer (score 7):

Paella is a specific type of rice dish, cooked in a wide, flat pan.  Although sesfood is typical, it can also be made without seafood.  (I typically just do chicken and sausage)

Casseroles, however, are typically a higher sided earthware or similar dish, and baked.  They typically have starch, but it might be rice, noodles, or a biscuit top.  They might use a cream based sauce, or cheese, which would not be included in a paella.

Answer (score 3):

I don't agree with the answer that states

"paella is a specific type of seafood casserole"

A Casserole is cooked in the oven (usually in a casserole dish or dutch oven), a paella should be cooked on the stove top in a paella pan or frying pan.

Answer (score 1):

Pealla is a specific type of seafood casserole.  Every square is a rhombus but not every rhombus is a square.